# Transition only for the border on hover, but not for background

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

**Here I have some CSS:**

```
    #image-edges-beneath:hover{
    background-color: blue;
    }

    #image-edges:hover{
      background-color: blue;
    }

    #image-edges-beneat:hover:after{
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
         -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
           -o-transition: all 1s ease;
          -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
              transition: all 1s ease;
      border: 2px solid #F1FD6D;
    }

    #image-edges:hover:after{
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
         -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
           -o-transition: all 1s ease;
          -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
              transition: all 1s ease;
      border: 2px solid #F1FD6D;
    }
```

However this does not work. The only thing which happens is that the background color has a transition while I want it to only change on hover, while the border I want to have a transition, so basically the border fades into the color while the background color changes color immediately upon hover. That's what I want to accomplish, but this doesn't work. :( 
Any ideas users?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

What you need to do is set which property you want to transistion properly. Currently you have it as "all" but it needs to be either "background-color" or "border-color" based on which you want to be transitioned.

```
 transition: border-color 1s ease;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u3Ahk/

Comment: Don't forget the prefixes for cross-browser support! `-webkit-transition:border-color 1s ease;
   -moz-transition:border-color 1s ease;
     -o-transition:border-color 1s ease;
        transition:border-color 1s ease;`

Answer (score 6):

You can do border effect in a lots of way.  Apply the below css to the class which you gonna apply border effect and change the border style on any event occurs.

```
 -webkit-transition:  border 3s ease;
 -moz-transition:  border 3s ease;
 -o-transition:  border 3s ease;
 -ms-transition: border 3s ease;
 transition: border 3s ease;
```

Also refer these links for advance border effects

https://codepen.io/giana/pen/yYBpVY

http://cssdeck.com/labs/10-crazy-effects-with-css3-border-transitions