# Transition button on slide but not on hover

Tags: css

I have a button that slides in and out of the page. I want to keep that transition. That same button has a different background color when you hover over it, but it is transitioning to that background color and I don't want that. How do I keep the transition on slide effect but get rid of the transition on hover effect. This is the original code with both slide and hover transition:

```css
button {
    width: 209px;
 cursor:pointer;
 position: absolute;
 left: 14px;
 -webkit-transition: 1s;
 -moz-transition: 1s;
 -o-transition: 1s;
 -ms-transition: 1s;
 transition: 1s;
}

button:hover {
 color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 background: rgb(90, 90, 90);
}
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

I have tried to put transition: 0s on the btn:hover, but it doesn't stop the fading to the hover color for 1s. It's still there. I want the hover color to work, just not take 1s to transition to that color.

Comment: So... do you want it to automatically be that color on hover or take like .2s to get to that color? Because it sounds like you want [this](http://jsfiddle.net/a18muj3q/1/) or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/a18muj3q/)

Comment: Target the property that is changed. For example if it slid in using `left` you would target the left property only for the transition: `transition: left 1s;` and if you wanted the background colour to also transition, just faster, you can comma separate: `transition: left 1s, background 0.5s;`

Comment: @BuddhistBeast I still need the transition there because the button is sliding in initially.

Comment: @misterManSam I'm going to try that now. I'll report back. Thanks.

Comment: I might be the only one experiencing this.. but in Chrome the button does not slide in.

Comment: @BuddhistBeast I didn't include the slide. That would require a hidden radio button and I didn't want to add that to this forum.

Comment: @misterManSam. I just tried what you are saying and it's not working for me. If I add this:: transition: right 1s; It makes all transitions not work.

Comment: It looks like his comment works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/a18muj3q/3/) . I have added a fake slide effect to represent the initial slide...

Comment: @kimberlyvoo - right, you can just specify each property... [like this example](http://jsbin.com/fazebe/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Ok thanks guys! I can see that it works. Thanks again. @misterManSam Do you want to put this as an answer so I can mark it as answered? I don't think I can do it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar question: [Transition only for the border on hover, but not for background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14401454/2930477)

You need to specify the CSS properties that you want to transition, like so:

```
transition: left 4s, background 1s, height 8s;
```

In this example the div will slide in over 4 seconds, the background will change in 1 second and the height will change in 8 seconds.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  background: #F00;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: left 4s, background 1s, height 8s;
  left: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
body:hover > div {
  left: 0;
  background: #000;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
Hover here
```